# Mac Lion icon change issue

Tags: mac, icons

My Mac is doing this weird thing. I changed the icon for my Documents and Downloads folder and everything is fine. The new icon shows up in the dock when I drop there. The problem is when I create a folder inside of Documents, the new icon instantly changes to that folder in the Documents folder. The blue folder shows up in the dock instead of the new icon. I take the folder out, and it reverts back to the icon. What is going on? I have tried using Candybar and doing the usual copy and paste method.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bit like the folder is in stack view in the Dock. This means that it will display the icons (stacked up) of its contents if it has any, instead of the icon of the folder itself.. In the context menu for the folder in the Dock, select “Display as — Folder”.